# firebase-tools cannot install, why?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I cannot install firebase-tools on my mac machine.
firebase-tools error, and after install , firebase init error
I searched this problem, but I can't find solution

i reinstalled node, firebase, node-pre-gyp....etc.

```
> sudo npm install -g firebase-tools 

npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase

> node-zopfli@1.4.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@8.4.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@8.4.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/Huks/.pyenv/shims/python2 -c import platform; print(platform.python_version());
gyp ERR! stack pyenv: python2: command not found
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.13
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.9
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:545:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64/zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64/zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64/zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)

> grpc@1.4.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/Huks/.pyenv/shims/python2 -c import platform; print(platform.python_version());
gyp ERR! stack pyenv: python2: command not found
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.13
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.9
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:545:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64/zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v57-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.4.1/node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.4.1 and node@8.4.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/Huks/.pyenv/shims/python2 -c import platform; print(platform.python_version());
gyp ERR! stack pyenv: python2: command not found
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.13
gyp ERR! stack   2.7.9
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:545:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-zopfli@1.4.0 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/node-zopfli):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-zopfli@1.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.4.1 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.4.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

- firebase-tools@3.9.2
  added 154 packages and updated 1 package in 76.424s

  > firebase login ==> ok
  >   firebase init

Comment: firebase login is done. but, firebase init is error. :(

Comment: gyp ERR is still but, now it works. i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

i too got same like errors in installing firebase tools then i tried to install changing project directory  worked for me .
I fixed the error this way,sometime it will help you. i changed the directory `cd C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules>`npm install -g firebase-tools`

Comment: thanks. it works. :) I did reinstall all library on my mac computer.